# reduce function not working in derived column in adf mapping data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create the derived column based on the condition that met the value and trying to do the summation of multiple matching column values dynamically. So I am using reduce function in ADF derived column mapping data flow. But the column is not getting created even the transformation is correct.

Columns from source

[image]

Derived column logic

[image]

Derived column data preview without the new columns as per logic

[image]

I could see only the fields from source but not the derived column fields. If I use only the array($$) I could see the fields getting created.

Derived column data preview with logic only array($$)

[image]

How to get the derived column with the summation of all the fields matching the condition?

We are getting data of 48 weeks forecast and the data to be prepared on monthly basis.

eg: Input data

[image]

Output data:

```
JAN
----
506  -- This is for first record i.e. (94 + 105 + 109 + 103 + 95)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `array($$)` in the reduce function has only one element, so that the reduce function can not accumulate the content of the matching columns correctly.

You can solve this by using two derived columns and a data flow parameter as follows:

1. **Create derived columns with pattern matching for each month-week** you did it before, but put the reference $$ into the value field, instead of the reduce(...) function. 
   This will create derived columns like jan0, jan1, etc. containing the copy of the original values. For example **Week 0 (1 Jan - 7 Jan) => 0jan** with value 95.
   This step gives you a predefined set of column names for each week, which you can use to summarize the values with specific column names.
2. **Define Data Flow parameters for each month** containing the month-week column names in a string array, like this:
   `ColNamesJan=['0jan' ,'1jan', etc.] ColNamesFeb=['0feb' ,'1feb', etc.] and so on.`
   You will use these column names in a reduce function to summarize the month-week columns to monthly column in the next step.
3. **Create a derived column for each month**, which will contain the monthly totals, and use the following reduce function to sum the weekly values: 
   `reduce(array(byNames($ColNamesJan)), 0, #acc + toInteger(toString(#item)),#result)`
   *Replace the parameter name accordingly.*

I was able to summarize the columns dynamically with the above solution.
Please let me know if you need more information (e.g. screenshots) to reproduce the solution.

**Update** -- Here are the screenshots from my test environment.
Data source (data preview):
[image: Data source]
Derived columns with pattern matching (settings)
[image: derived columns with pattern matching settings]
Derived columns with pattern matching (data preview)
[image: derived columns with pattern matching preview]
Data flow parameter:
[image: data flow parameter]
Derived column for monthly sum (settings):
[image: derived column for monthly sum settings]
Derived column for monthly sum (data preview):
[image: derived column for monthly sum data preview]

Comment: Thanks for your solution Thomas. I will try with the steps you provided. And it helps if you can share the screenshots of your solution. Another point which I would like to add as part of the requirement is the forecast week which I got is considering the current month as Jan so Week 0 with Jan1 - Jan 7. Later point when the forecast report is generated like in feb, mar and so on months the week details for Jan will fall some where like Week46, week47 and so on as the current month will be in feb which starts week0 as Feb1-Feb7. So column names to be in dynamic fashion to get the summaries.

Comment: Thomas, I getting null values for the derived column 'JAN' with the below formula. reduce(array(byNames($ColNamesJan)), 0, #acc + toInteger(toString(#item)),#result)   I have added the paramter "ColNamesJan" of type "string[]" with values ['0Jan' ,'1Jan','2Jan','3Jan' ,'4Jan','5Jan','6Jan' ,'7Jan','8Jan','9Jan' ,'10Jan','11Jan','12Jan' ,'13Jan','14Jan']. For now I have given till 14Jan. But in actual it comes from 0Jan till 47Jan representing 48weeks depends on the month the forecast is generated.

Comment: The flow I have create is   source --> derived field (Generate the field like 0Jan, 1Jan and so on) --> derived field (to aggregate the derived fields of 0Jan, 1Jan ....) based on array(byNames(['0Jan','1Jan'])) with hardcoded field names to test the output I could able to see as [{},{}] in the 2nd derived field. Seems something I am missing here. Can you please provide your screenshots that helps to replicate the solution.

Comment: @KarthikB I've updated the answer with my screenshots. I think, you get NULL in the column JAN because at least one of the week-moth columns does not exist, so the reduce function has a silent exception.

Comment: @KarthikB I see from your comment above that you also want the month string to be dynamic. This is a new requirement compared to the original question. To handle this, you need to save the month in a pipeline variable string based on the time of the pipeline trigger. Then you need to pass it as parameter to the to the data flow. Please upvote and accept my answer if you think it answers your question,  so that you can help other users to find the solution to the original question.